# Db2 error when inserting with PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()

Tags: kotlin, jdbc, db2

I'm creating support for db2 database in my library
and I have code that works on multiple SQL database that supports jdbc

But db2 is giving me an issue when trying to use existing codebase
when trying to insert to database table with prepared statement
like this...

```sql
INSERT INTO main.Parent (col) VALUES (?);
```

I got error like this...

```bash
Caused by: com.urosjarc.dbmessiah.exceptions.EngineException: Failed to process insert results from: 

INSERT INTO main.Parent (col) VALUES (?);

    1) col: VARCHAR = '-1934310868'

Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=;;ent (col) VALUES (?);<space>, DRIVER=4.33.31
```

The jdbc side is standard and I know it should be working...

```kotlin
        var ps: PreparedStatement? = null
        var rs: ResultSet? = null
        var rs2: ResultSet? = null

        //Execute query
        try {
            //Prepare statement
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query.sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)
            
            //Custom logic for inserting values to result set...
            ps.setString(1, "asdf")

            //Get info
            val numUpdates = ps.executeUpdate()

            //If no updates happend close all
            if (numUpdates == 0) {
                this.closeAll(ps = ps)
                return null
            }
            //Continue with getting ids for inserts
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            this.closeAll(ps = ps)
            throw EngineException(msg = "Failed to process insert results from: $query", cause = e)
        }
```

If I run the same query over jetbrains idea db console

```sql
INSERT INTO main.Parent (col) VALUES (?);
```

The insertion is working...

I'm using jdbc driver...

```
                this.runtimeOnly("com.ibm.db2:jcc:11.5.9.0")
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Which language you are talking about?

Comment: Where so you bind the paramater?

Comment: This is kotlin and the binding parameters occures in `this.prepareQuery(ps = ps, query = query)` the code that I have pasted on the issue is heavly e2e tested on all major sql databases and it works for them but db2 fails...

Comment: Please share an [mcve]

Comment: @Jens I have fixed the example in the issue to be more transparent.

Comment: try to remove the `; ` at the end of the statement

Comment: @Jens OMG Its freaking working now :D Can you elaborate more about this issue I want to understand... Please create an answere so that I can confirm it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `;` at the end of the statement.

JDBC doesn't support multiple statements and `;` is the statement delimiter. So it will lead in an error.

Comment: But this is not problem of JDBC on postgresql and SQL server multiple statements works joust fine... Probably this is limitation of underlying driver?